# Unix command to get lines not containing certain text

Tags: unix, grep, cat

I have a UNIX log file which contains 1000K lines. Most of the file has lines:

```
07 Apr 2015 17:54:23.854: Read 0 Messages
```

I read file using `cat filename`

I would like to read lines that don't contain a specific text -`'Read 0 Messages'`

I tried below commands:

```
cat filename|grep '^{Read 0 Messages}'
cat filename|grep '!{Read 0 Messages}'
```

Can you advice me correct command?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`grep` can do it:

```
grep -v "'Read 0 Messages'" file
```

The `-v` option is used to indicate what you *do not* want to be printed.

From `man grep`:

> -v, --invert-match
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.  (-v is
>   specified by POSIX.)

Also, note there is no need to `cat file | grep '...'`. You can directly say `grep '...' file`.